error loading cloud-init config: bad file
I am trying to create a local kubernetes cluster using cloud-init and multipass on my local ubuntu machine.
This is my config file:
#cloud-config
package_update: true
packages:
  - debootstrap
users:
  - name: root
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: tersu
ssh_pwauth: true
disable_root: false
runcmd:
  - debootstrap --arch=arm64 bookworm /mnt http://deb.debian.org/debian/
  - mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
  - mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
  - mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-image-arm64 systemd-sysv"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "apt-get install -y grub-efi"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "grub-install --target=arm64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-debian --recheck"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "update-grub"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main' > /etc/apt/sources.list"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "echo 'root:password' | chpasswd"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "systemctl enable ssh"
  - umount /mnt/dev
  - umount /mnt/proc
  - umount /mnt/sys
  - echo "Debian installation completed!"

This is the script to create the vms:
#!/bin/bash

# Launch VMs with multipass
multipass launch --name jumpbox --cpus 1 --memory 512M --disk 5G --cloud-init ./config/debian-cloud-init.yaml
multipass launch --name master --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init ./config/debian-cloud-init.yaml
multipass launch --name worker1 --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init ./config/debian-cloud-init.yaml
multipass launch --name workder2 --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init ./config/debian-cloud-init.yaml

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:
error loading cloud-init config: bad file
error loading cloud-init config: bad file
error loading cloud-init config: bad file
error loading cloud-init config: bad file

yaml lint:
yamllint config/debian-cloud-init.yaml                                                                                       10:33:58
config/debian-cloud-init.yaml
  1:2       warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  2:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
  16:81     error    line too long (98 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  18:81     error    line too long (118 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  20:81     error    line too long (109 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  22:81     error    line too long (103 > 80 characters)  (line-length)

The cloud-init schema seems to be valid:
cloud-init schema --config-file config/debian-cloud-init.yaml                                                                11:25:36
2024-09-24 10:25:46,092 - sources[WARNING]: failed loading pickle in /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl'
2024-09-24 10:25:46,122 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed pickling datasource to /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl
2024-09-24 10:25:46,123 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceNone.DataSourceNone'> failed
2024-09-24 10:25:46,131 - schema.py[WARNING]: datasource not detected, using default instance-data/user-data paths.
Valid schema config/debian-cloud-init.yaml

multipass version
multipass   1.14.0
multipassd  1.14.0

multipass driver
multipass get local.driver                                                                                                   11:27:29
qemu

what could be the issue? or what am I missing?


what am I missing?

I assume that you just cross-posted this here and missed my response on the identical Github issue that was filed earlier today.

what could be the issue?

The issue is that cloud-init didn't even get a configuration. This issue is outside of cloud-init and is caused by one of the following:

an issue with your configuration file
a bug in multipass or one of its dependencies
an issue in your image (if you are building your own image)

Please see my response in the bug report if you haven't already.

yes, I shared it here for wider reach. I have responded to your comment. I have also shared a link to the files I am working with on github.

@DavidEssien continuing the conversation there
